# Easy Sum formula

Tags: worksheet-function, vlookup

What formula do I use for the total sum of a and b?

```
1   a                               
2   b                               
3   a                               
4   b                               
5   a                               
6   b                               
7   a                               
8   b                               
9   a                               
10  b
```

Total

a____

b____

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sumif() to sum all values in column A where column B equals a specific value.

=SUMIF(B1:B10,"a",A1:A10)

[image]

Comment: Ahh... the "  "  is what I left off.  Thank you!

Comment: Please mark this as the answer if you want to say thank you.